# Word or Phrase for People Who Claim to be a Professional to Increase Their Credibility

Tags: expressions

What is a word or phrase for someone who claims to be a professional to increase the credibility or weight of their opinion?

I'm looking for something along the lines of ad hominem, but for the correct scenario.

Comment: You mean a 'charlatan'? : a person who makes elaborate, fraudulent, and often voluble claims to skill or knowledge.

Comment: @mplungjan I can see why he did that, especially since it's for the title, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Self-proclaimed expert?

Comment: A "so-called" professional?
A "self-proclaimed" professional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I thought about an answer like Josh61's charlatan (which I think is a good one). However, after re-reading your "something along the lines of *ad hominem* I think that perhaps you are refering to the logical fallacy of claiming one's reputation in order to 'prove' a point. If that is the case, I think that you may want be looking for ***ad verecundiam*** or ***argument from authority***